# Magento 2: Custom module error Class OAuth\Common\Storage\Session does not exist

Tags: magento2, error, magento2.4.2, setup-di-compile

I have using Magento 2.4.2 enterprise edition and install custom module after run command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` and then run command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` but facing error while run command `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` using custom module.

I have also tried some solutions like adding permission and `remove var/*` `pub/static/*` `generated/*` but the issue is not resolved.

**Error:**

```
Class OAuth\Common\Storage\Session does not exist                                                                                                                    
  Class Vendor\Module\Controller\Google\Login\Interceptor generation error: The requested class did not generate properly because the 'generated' directory permission is read-only. If --- after running the 'bin/Magento setup:di: compile' CLI command when the 'generated' directory permission is set to write --- the re  
  the quested class did not generate properly, then you must add the generated class object to the signature of the related construct method, only.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix the issue to add `lusitanian/oauth` package. actually lusitanian/oauth package was missing. added package via below command.

**Command:**
`composer require lusitanian/oauth`

After run command issue has resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the /generated/code/* then run setup:di:compile

Comment: I have already removed /generated/code/*  but not working.

Comment: Give permission to chmod 777 -R var pub generated folder.if it will help

Comment: Tried that solution but not works.

Comment: okay then check your env.php file if sessions are correctly set up there are either DB or files.